# Applying custom role to user

Tags: mongodb

I am having trouble creating custom roles in MongoDB and assigning them to users.  I followed this guide to create a custom role to be the same as readWrite, but without the dropCollection privilege:

https://hackernoon.com/mongodb-createrole-e1ca1346d3bb

These are the instructions I followed from that article:

```
use admin
db.createRole({
  role: "readWriteMinusDropRole",
  privileges: [
  {
    resource: { db: "social", collection: ""},
    actions: [ "collStats", "dbHash", "dbStats", "find", "killCursors", "listIndexes", "listCollections", "convertToCapped", "createCollection", "createIndex", "dropIndex", "insert", "remove", "renameCollectionSameDB", "update"]} ],
    roles: []
  }
);
```

Creating the role worked just fine, but when I use:

```
use admin
db.grantRolesToUser(
"P-DXdbUser",
[ "readWriteMinusDropRole" , ] )
```

It will add the role to the user, but the role does not seem to do anything.  When I execute this command from P-DXdbUser:

```
use TestDB
db.getCollection('TestCollection').getIndexes()
```

It does not return any results.  I did substitute TestDB for social in this spot in the instruction webpage:

```
resource: { db: "social", collection: ""},
```

But it doesn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the relevant Json for P-DXdbUser:

```
{
    "_id" : "DX.dxdbuser",
    "user" : "dxdbuser",
    "db" : "DX",
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "DX"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "LoadTracking"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "MacroPoint"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "LoadPosting"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWriteMinusDropRole",
            "db" : "TestDB"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to restrict the user's access with this role to all the databases, but for now, I am only messing with the TestDB.

Comment: Just to be sure : is there any collection in testDB? Otherwise, there's no index too. If role was not applied, mongodb must throw an error with no access allowed. But no result means that user can run the command on the database.

Comment: Yes.  I have 2 collections in it.  Placeholder I created to make sure the db didn't just disappear because it had no data, and TestCollection is the collection I would like to interact with (the whole goal here is to create a user role with readWrite access, but without the ability to drop collections).

Comment: Also, when I try to expand the collections using Robo 3T from the dxdbuser, I get this error:
Failed to refresh 'Collections'.

Error:
ListCollections failed: {operationTime: Timestamp 1538604088000|1, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "not authorized on TestDB to execute command {listCollections: 1, filter: {}, cursor: {}, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "TestDB" }", code: 13, codeName: "Unauthorized" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after several hours of experimentation, I have finally figured out what I was doing wrong, and how that guide I used misled me.

In order to apply a role to a user, you have to apply it to the database that the role is a part of.  In this case, that database is admin (and I am unsure as to whether you can add roles to databases other than admin).  According to the tutorial, you are supposed to create the role in admin, but then specify the database you want it to apply to when granting the role to a user.  This is incorrect, and it was very confusing to me as to why it would be necessary since within the role itself you need to specify what databases you need to permit actions for.

The answer is that you DO specify the databases you want a role to have permissions to perform actions on within the role itself, NOT when granting that role to a user.  When granting that role to a user, you need to specify the database that the role is a member of!  That's it!  Here are the code snippets that resolved my issue..

This is the Json for the ROLE I created (I will be changing the name now that I am done testing):

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.readWriteMinusDropRoleTest",
    "role" : "readWriteMinusDropRoleTest",
    "db" : "admin",
    "privileges" : [ 
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "TestDB",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [ 
                "collStats", 
                "convertToCapped", 
                "createCollection", 
                "createIndex", 
                "dbHash", 
                "dbStats", 
                "dropIndex", 
                "find", 
                "insert", 
                "killCursors", 
                "listCollections", 
                "listIndexes", 
                "remove", 
                "renameCollectionSameDB", 
                "update"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "roles" : []
}
```

Notice that the db that the role is a member of is "admin", but the db specified as the resource it can interact with is "TestDB".

Here is the relevant Json for the user:

```
{
    "role" : "readWriteMinusDropRoleTest",
    "db" : "admin"
}
```

By specifying the admin db, I can now interact with TestDB as I intended using this user account.